Mysql problem not valid syntax

reason:Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'почта VARCHAR(50), тип травмы ENUM('физическая', 'э' at line 9
where did I go wrong?

Schema Object Names - study carefully. Especially the part about quoting.

Column name тип травмы has a blank (space) in it. That is not allowed. The most common solution is to replace the space by an underscore, like this:
тип_травмы
Another option is to use a quoted identifier:
"тип травмы"
but that makes your code more complicated as it requires each reference to the column to also use quotes. Using underscores is IMO a much simpler solution.

In MySQL this needs in ANSI_QUOTES server SQL mode. Otherwise the value will be treated as string literal which is a syntax error too.

Or use backtics (```) around identificers.
